# tomcat 6 crash on heavy post

Tags: servlets, post, tomcat6

I try to load, edit and send back a text file trougth forms with the post method.
It works well, but when the file exceed a certain size (around 1200Ko), the programm crash beacause the request act as if it does not have any parameter.
What cause it to act like this? And how do I remove this limit?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

visit http://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-memory
You will read here how to avoid crashes in Tomcat 6 and fixing the related issues

Out Of Memory Errors, or OOMEs, are one of the most common problems faced by Apache Tomcat users.  Generally, these errors occur during development, but can even occur on production servers that are experiencing an unusually high spike of traffic.  Tomcat 7 includes fixes and workarounds to prevent some of the causes of OOMEs, but nothing substitutes a good understanding of why these errors occur.

This guide will help you understand why these errors are so prevalent and seemingly hard to fix, and show you how organizations using Apache Tomcat in enterprise production environments use Tcat to fix and avoid these errors.

OutOfMemoryError messages, or OOME's, are one of the most common problems that users experience with Tomcat.  These messages can be caused by a wide variety of factors, and they severely affect application performance, so it's a good idea to do everything you can to prevent them before they occur.  Here are the most common OOME-triggering situations, and steps to help you avoid them in the future. Tcat's management console gives you deep visibility into the memory stats of your Tomcat instances, allowing you to eliminate memory leaks and tune your servers more quickly than ever.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I do not get any OOME message in my situation. My IDE just tell me that the resust does not have the parameter it should have, and this happen when I send a lot of data in my textarea. Can it still be an OOME regardless?